# IE11 in Parallels Desktop is using wrong css code?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, flexbox, parallels, codekit

I was testing some css code in IE11 in Parallels desktop as I often do, using Codekit 2 as server/sass compiler. The Flexbox code was not working as it should.

I looked in the F12 window and it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, all the ms-related flexbox code is marked as invalid and it's trying to use the webkit code, as if the user agent is Safari.

Why would this happen and how can I be sure IE is using it own user agent?

Comment: No, you misinterpret the results. `-ms-flexbox` is not invalid, it is _overridden_ by the property following it, `display:flex`.

Comment: Yes, but my CSS lists all the CSS methods for flexbox as output by autoprefixer. Each browser is supposed to use the one it needs and ignore the others.

Comment: `-ms-flexbox` is an older variant that is used only by IE10. IE11 (and, presumably, Edge) uses the latest version of the standard. So yes, `flex` is the one it _should_ be using. All is well.